# Module action permissions in activecollab

Tags: php, model, permissions, module, activecollab

I am working on activecollab custom module, facing problem in permissions; I have added permissions with the help of "on_system_permissions.php" handler. But the thing is how can I check this on code that either the logged in user have permission of specific action or not ..

I got below code from activecollab other module:

```
class Role extends FwRole implements IHomescreen {

..
..

    function isPeopleManager(){

       $this->getPermissionValue('can_manage_people');

    }
...
...

}
```

Is that to check permission of any action? or it just return a value of that action?

In above class they are using **$this->** and extending a class by **FwRole** .. When i using `FwRole::getPermissionValue('can_manage_people');` to get return it gives me error of $this and object ..

So my question is how we can check permission of specific action in code and how i can use getPermissionValue() function to retrieve permission either yes or not ..

Comment: Post here what have You tried and don't forget about the concrete error message.

Comment: thanks for your response ..
when I use `FwRole::getPermissionValue('can_manage_people');` it gives me this error ... `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in D:\wamp\www\activecollab\public\activecollab\3.0.9\angie\frameworks\authentication\models\roles\FwRole.class.php on line 153`

the basic thing that i need to know is how can i check permissions on code for my module ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a user instance, you can check whether that user has particular permission set to Yes by executing `getSystemPermission` method:

```
$user = Users::findById(12);

if($user instanceof User) {
  if($user->getSystemPermission('my_permission')) {
    print 'My permission set to Yes';
  } else {
    print 'My permission set to No';
  } // if
} // if
```

Note that activeCollab permissions cascade (can depend one on another). If you have dependent permission, system also checks whether you have parent permissions set to Yes, not just that (for example, system will return false for `manage_projects` permission if you don't have `system_access` permission, because it depends on it).

**Update**

Permission cascading has been introduced in activeCollab 3!

Comment: If that covers you, mark the answer as the one that closes this question. I'm kind of obsessed about questions that are tagged with activeCollab tag and want to have them all answered and closed :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that You call $this but You are not in object context - that is because You call method `getPermissionValue` in a **static** context...

In Your code where You call `FwRole::getPermissionValue('can_manage_people');` You have to do this:

```
$role = new FwRole; // if it needs a parameter in constructor, call it like new FwRole($param);
$permission_value = $role->getPermissionValue('permission');
```

By creating an instance of class FwRole You create the FwRole object thus You are in object context and the error (You provided) is gone.